# Saving image path in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to store image path in MySQL. I created a `varchar` column and tried inserting image path but it removes all backslashes. Is my approach correct? Is there a better way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are used to escape certain characters in a string. Try doubling your backslashes.

Example:

```
\\folder\\folder\\file
```

Comment: Thanks it works.I'm storing images in subsolders in htcdoc in xammp but when i give full path i cannot fetch them but when they are in same folder as my file they are fetched any way around it?

Comment: Access to certain directories is determined in the Apache config file, have a look in there.